# IIS6 SMTP Service and stop Delivery Reties?

Tags: iis-6, smtp

Is there anyway to tell the SMTP service to stop trying to resend an e-mail that has been tried / failes x amount of times ? I can't find anything in the delivery tab to speicify this. Just curious if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Expiration Timeout. I was thinking that was something differnt.